# Fullpage.js: Page is scrolling too fast

Tags: fullpage.js

I have a fullpage.js site at the following link that is made up of 2 sections: 1 with a few slides, and a second section which is very long, and which takes some scrolling to navigate.

http://www.heartpatrick.com/indexnew.html

I noticed that the second section scrolls considerably faster now after i have implemented fullpage.js compared to what it used to behave previously. This happens both on a laptop using the mouse wheel, and on my iphone. I also don't get the smooth momentum scrolling effect on my iphone anymore, different from last time.

Can you tell what did I do wrong with my codes?

Thanks all! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also don't get the smooth momentum scrolling effect on my iphone anymore, different from last time.

That's an already known issue when using `scrollOverflow: true` as you can see [in this topic](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/506).

Regarding the speed. I see it normal. If you see it in the same way [in this demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html), then there's nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting `scrollingSpeed` to your liking. 
Look up the Initialization section in the [docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs).